# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, runtime-error

When I run my app on a iOS 8+ or later device, it runs perfectly with no errors but when I run it on a iOS 7.1 device the app crashes with this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xedc5fc'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0098a1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x004d58e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00a270e3 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0097a50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0097a0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Origami Game                        0x0002161f -[GBAGameScene initWithSize:] + 495
    6   Origami Game                        0x000281b4 -[GBAMenuScene touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 500
    7   SpriteKit                           0x00e102bf -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 824
    8   UIKit                               0x00f64c0b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x00f659d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    10  UIKit                               0x00f375f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    11  UIKit                               0x00f21353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0091377f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0091310b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x009301ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0092f9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0092f7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x025245ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0252442b GSEventRun + 104
    19  UIKit                               0x00f23f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    20  Origami Game                        0x00026d5d main + 141
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x02a756d9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I don't know what's happening, my app uses the Sprite Kit framework and I'm not using the storyboards, just code.

Comment: Look at the docs for the method giving you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init method `initWithText:` which is called by the class method `[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:]` was only added in iOS 8 so you cannot call this method in iOS 7. As a workaround use:

```
SKLabelNode *lbl=[SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed: "Arial"];
lbl.text="hello world";
```

To find which methods are available on which OS look at the docs.

(sorry if my obj-c isn't right or the method has a different name)